# After creating ICMP object it is showing error message in exception as?

Tags: c#, .net

I got error as manhandled exception in pinglib.dll while creating object of ICMP class in pivo.ping.
It is working on one machine but same code is not working on another machine.
Please rectify.
It is showing MSG=????????????

```
void main()
  {
   try
     {
      ICMP obj=new ICMP();
     }
   catch(Exception ex)
     {
        string msg=ex.Message();
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
     }
   }
```

}

Comment: Object created as follows   using Pivo.ping;
using System.Io;


Class Test
{

 void main()
 {
   try
   {
      ICMP obj=new ICMP();
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      string msg=ex.Message();
      Console.WriteLine(msg);
   }
 }
}

Comment: Please provide more information about the problem, like a piece of code, and the exception you are getting. And edit the question instead of adding comments.

Comment: Please add some code. Don't try to put it in the comments. *edit* your question, copy and paste the code in, highlight the block and hit the `{}` button.

Comment: Where can we find `pinglib`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why aren't you using the standard `Ping` method [included in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

```
Ping pingSender = new Ping ();
PingReply reply = pingSender.Send ("www.contoso.com");
```

Comment: it is .net framework 2.0 based project. I cant change the code.

Comment: @Sagar - [`Ping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.80).aspx) was included in .NET 2.0

Comment: i added pinglib.dll, i think its not related to code or dll, may be other problem. Because same code project is working on other machine...